# Inline Forms in Django 1.1 Admin Panel

Tags: python, django

How do you display forms for the children of a specific model in the Django Admin Panel?

```
class Matchup(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    winner      = models.ForeignKey('players.player',blank=True)        

class Slot(models.Model):
    player  = models.ForeignKey('players.player',blank=True)
    matchup = models.ForeignKey(Matchup)
```

Each matchup will have two slots - how would I go about displaying forms for both of them in line with the Match.

Basically, I want to have something like this:

```
Matchup Name:     [         ]
Matchup Winner:   [         ]
--
== Slot 1 ==
|| Slot Player:   [         ]
== Slot 2 ==
|| Slot Player:   [         ]
```

I realize it may appear that the slot model is useless and should just be replaced by two references to players, but there are various reasons I want to do it this way.

**EDIT:** removed confusing associations

Comment: I don't understand why you have Matchup.winner and win_slot.winner also.  And doesn't this already show up this way in the admin?

Comment: Ah, yeah - to clarify: the slots attached via the foreign key and the slots attached via win_slot and lose_slot are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from models import *

class SlotInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Slot

class MatchupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Matchup
    inlines = [SlotInline]

admin.site.register(Matchup, MatchupAdmin)
```

Comment: Follow up question: I want the Slots to be saved upon the creation of a Matchup, even if they aren't modified in any way (e.g. all fields left blank) - is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: I think this will accomplish that as long as the Slots model allows for blank entries.  Is this not happening?

Comment: Nope - it works without error, but does not create the slots unless I provide some information for them. I have allow blank and allow null on their fields.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/500/